# antlr4 - how to implement recursion

Tags: java, recursion, antlr, antlr4

I want to parse the following input:

```
<name 1> WITH <name 2> WITH <name 3> WITH <name 4> ...
```

I tried the following grammar:

```
WITH        : 'WITH'
            ;
NAME        : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9' | '-' | '_')+
            ;
query       : NAME (WITH query)?
            ;
```

But this does not seem to work. How can I implement recursion?

**for your information**

My end goal is to parse a tree-like structure like this:

```
<name 1> WITH (<name 2> WITH <name 3> WITH <name 4>) WITH <name 5>
```

This produces the following tree:

```
<name 1>
  <name 2>
    <name 3>
    <name 4>
  <name 5>
```

But let's first start with the first expression.

My code:

```
new TParser(new CommonTokenStream(new TLexer(new ANTLRInputStream( "hello WITH world" )))).query()
```

resulted in the message:

```
line 1:16 no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'
```

Comment: @BartKiers: I added it as comment on your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Cool, thanks, It's always a good idea to copy-paste exact error messages in your original post (you can edit your question after submitting it).

Comment: I will do that in the future. I am new to SO, thanks for pointing that out. Also thanks for adding it to my message already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding a lexer rule that consumes (and skips) spaces, I have no problem.

The grammar:

```
grammar T;

SPACE       : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip
            ;
WITH        : 'WITH'
            ;
NAME        : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9' | '-' | '_')+
            ;
query       : NAME (WITH query)?
            ;
```

will match the input `a WITH b WITH c WITH d` as follows:

[image]

Note that your `NAME` rule can be written as follows:

```
NAME        : [a-zA-Z0-9_-]+
            ;
```

To get rid of the `EOF` message, simply introduce an entry point to your grammar that ends with `EOF`:

```
parse : query EOF;
```

and then do:

```
new TParser(...).parse()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! When I try your grammar (I copy/pasted it), I get the following error: 'line 1:16 no viable alternative at input '<EOF>''.

Comment: My code: `new TParser(new CommonTokenStream(new TLexer(new ANTLRInputStream(
                "hello WITH world"
        )))).query()`

Comment: Thanks! I did not realize you have to explicitly take `EOF` into account.

Comment: By the way. I tried to upvote your answer, but I don't have enough reputation points yet. I will do it later once I have them.